# Cassandra Authentication Exception in java

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I am using DataStax driver for connecting to a Cassandra node. below is the code for the connector.

```
public void connect(String node, Integer port, String username, String password) throws Exception {
        try {
            Builder b = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).withCredentials(username.trim(), password.trim());
            if (port != null) {
                b.withPort(port);
            }
            cluster = b.build();

            session = cluster.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("can not connect to the node :"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I have set the authenticator in Cassandra.yaml file

> authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator

on calling the connect method the following error is being shown:

> Authentication error on host localhost/127.0.0.1:9042: Host
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 requires authentication, but no authenticator
>   found in Cluster configuration

cqlsh shell is able to connect to the node using same configurations for the Cassandra. Can anyone tell what's I am missing here?

Edit : 
Exception Stack
at

> com.datastax.driver.core.AuthProvider$1.newAuthenticator(AuthProvider.java:40)
>     at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$5.apply(Connection.java:259)
>     at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$5.apply(Connection.java:244)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$AsyncTransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:211)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$AsyncTransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:200)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture.run(AbstractTransformFuture.java:130)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:902)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:813)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:655)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Future.onSet(Connection.java:1302)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1083)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1006)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:141)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: What version of Java Driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

The error was due to some background threads trying to connect to the server without authentication, these were left unterminated in a previous debugging session!